# Richfaces select element does not render drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I need an editable drop down menu with rich faces. Here is my code.

```
<rich:select enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="start typing for select">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="label1" itemValue="iv1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="label2" itemValue="iv2"/>
</rich:select>
```

The above code does not display an editable drop down menu. It only displays an input text box with items listed below it. When I start typing in the text box, the list disappears.

Screenshot:

[image: Problem]

What is causing this problem? I tried this with richfaces 4.3.2 and 4.3.4. Both gave me same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had incorrect settings in web.xml. The following configuration works:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>classic</param-value>
    </context-param>
```